# System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Failed to process the request

Tags: c#, wcf, newrelic

I am seeing a strange issue, that I haven't been able to track down. I see this error quite a bit pertaining to a 3rd party API that I am calling in a production environment. Its a critical API, but the error doesn't seem to be causing any issue, IE:The call seems to be successful. This error only shows up in NewRelic. We also log exceptions to a file, and the file has no errors in it! I've tried to reproduce the issue in my development environment, but have not seen it occur.

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Failed to process the request
>   Stack trace at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)

What is strange about this stacktrace, is I don't see ThrowIfFaultUnderstood at the top of the stack. And since the call seems to be successful even though I see an error in NewRelic, I am left confused about how I can track down a root cause.